# Calling the username of a devise user model in rails when trying to show ownership of posts/comments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a devise User model with the username:string attribute added in.  Posts belong to a User and Comments belong to a post and a user.  I want to display the posts/comments owners' usernames in my views.  I am getting this error message: undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass

This is what I have in my view:

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
<div class="comments well">
<p><%= comment.user.username %></p>
<p><%= comment.body %></p>
</div>



<% end %>
```

comments controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
def index
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
@comments = @post.comments.order('created_at desc')
end

def new
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
@comment = @post.comments.new(params[:id])

end


def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)

  @comment.post_id = @post.id 
  @comment.user_id = current_user.id

if @comment.save
  redirect_to post_comments_path(@post)
else

  redirect_to new_post_comment_path(post)
end
end

def destroy
end
```

private

```
def comment_params
params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :post_id)
end
end
```

I'm not sure why username is undefined, I set the user_id to the current_user's id..Shouldn't that do the trick?  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This indicates that the comment's user is null.  Make sure the user_id attribute is set on each comment. You might try setting `comment.user_id = current_user.id`